# Row level security (RLS) in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, row-level-security

Please let me know if any one has implemented RLS security in Azure Databricks. Looks like this is not possible but wanted to post here and see if anyone has implemented this or faced this requirement and what was done to overcome this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [Table Access Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/table-acls/object-privileges) in order to provide fine-grained access over tables defined on object storage. Table ACLs are based off views, but if that is not sufficient you can look at other solutions like [Privacera](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/11/21/how-databricks-and-privacera-combine-to-secure-data-for-cloud-analytics.html) or [Immuta](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/12/10/new-data-governance-tool-simplifies-analytics-compliance.html) that give more advanced capabilities for defining policies over tables.

Answer (score 2):

To get a sense for how these solutions work, you can get a trial from [www.immuta.com/try](http://www.immuta.com/try) and here is a tutorial on [row-level access controls using Immuta for Databricks on Azure](https://www.immuta.com/row-and-cell-level-access-controls-using-databricks/):

Full disclosure: My team produces content for data engineers at Immuta and I hope this helps save you some time in your research.